# Keyboard and mouse don't work after kexec

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kexec

While installing Fedora on my MacBook Pro Mid 2012 I've occasionally used `kexec` command to "boot" from live environment to the installed system.

```
# yum install kexec-tools.x86_64
# mount LABEL=/boot /mnt
# kexec --append 'root=UUID=... rw' \
        --initrd /mnt/initramfs-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64.img \
        /mnt/vmlinuz-3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64
```

This worked, but I had to connect USB keyboard and mouse because the the integrated ones suddenly stopped working. I've never used `kexec` before, so I'd like to know if this is "by design" or just a bug? Or may be somebody know how to work this around? I suspect it was caused by non-hotpluggable PS/2 bus, if so, is there a way to properly reinitialize it?

Comment: Also, would someone kindly create "kexec" tag?

Comment: I experienced this exact issue, using kexec to jump from 3.16 to 4.4, except it was very intermittent— every few boots the USB peripherals would work, but mostly they wouldn't. Jumping to 4.8 instead seems to have resolved the issue for me.